# Is there difference between "spectral decomposition" and "singular value decomposition"?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, ridge-regression

Am I right that "spectral decomposition" for symmetric matrix and "singular value decomposition" for non square matrix? Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: [Search our site!](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=svd%20spectral)  Oh--I see that a previous question of yours is the top hit.  What precisely do you need explained that isn't already answered there?

Comment: @ huber - I wish I had.  In a moment, well 15 minutes of boredom, I answered the question :)